# 3D Vectors wrap on the Sphere

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, vector

How I can wrap the 3D vectors around the sphere surface like this one. [image]

My angles are

```
θ[x_, y_] := π (1 - Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/R^2)]); 
ϕ[x_, y_ ] := ArcTan[x, y] - Pi/2;
```

With

```
{Cos[ϕ[x, y ]] Sin[θ[x, y]], Sin[ϕ[x, y ]] Sin[θ[x, y]], Cos[θ[x, y]]}.
```

Comment: What about a 3D vector field wherein that is the outer most orientation of the vectors then do a 3D sphere insert via `Epilog` or something similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Create a mesh

```
mesh[θ_,n_]:=Table[{Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ],Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ],Cos[θ]},{ϕ,π/n,2 π,(2 π)/n}];
p={{0,1},{π/6,6},{2π/6,9},{3π/6,12},{4π/6,9},{5π/6,6},{π,1}};
points=Join[Flatten[mesh[#[[1]],#[[2]]]&/@p,1]];
```

- There are 7 θ-slices: `{0, π/6, 2π/6, 3π/6, 4π/6, 5π/6, π}`. The number of `ϕ`-points in each slice is different for esthetic reasons.
- `p` contains data of the form `{θ,n}`: how many `ϕ`-points is
  needed for each `θ` value.
- `points` is a combined list of points where the vector field is plotted.

---

### Define a field

```
field[x_,y_,z_]:=Module[{θ,ϕ},ϕ=If[x^2+y^2>0,ArcTan[x,y],0];θ=ArcTan[z,Sqrt[x^2+y^2]];
{-Sin[ϕ]Sin[θ],Cos[ϕ]Sin[θ],Cos[θ]}]
```

We will be plotting a skyrmion with *winding number* 1, as requested in the OP. Other customizations are possible. For instance one can consider higher-order [skyrmions,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_skyrmion) or skyrmions with opposite *topological charge*---*antiskyrmions*.

### Combine vector plot and a sphere

```
g1=VectorPlot3D[field[x,y,z],{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},{z,-1,1},VectorPoints->points,VectorStyle->"Arrow3D",VectorColorFunction->Function[{x,y,z,vx,vy,vz,n},ColorData["Rainbow"][z]],Axes->False];
g2=Graphics3D[Sphere[{0,0,0},0.9]];
Show[{g1,g2},Boxed->False,ImageSize->Large]
```

[image]

Some interesting reading is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/360856/non-chiral-skyrmion-v-s-left-right-chiral-skyrmion).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also, thank you for sharing that link.

Answer (score 7):

You can actually use a built-in function called **SliceVectorPlot3D**:

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[{y, -x, z}, "CenterSphere", {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

to get:

[image]