# Plotting 3D data in (Fr, Fθ, Fz) cylindrical coordinates

Tags: plotting, vector

[image: A skyrmion]

I want to plot a skyrmion (like shown above) represented by a 3D vectorial arrows but showing in a 2D plane.

My code is as follows:

```
λ = 633*10^(-9);
ω = 2*π*3*10^8/λ;
k0 = 2 π/λ;
kr = 1.05*k0;
kz = Sqrt[kr^2 - k0^2];
Fr = 
  Plot[{0.8*kz*kr^2/(2*ω)*1/r*BesselJ[1, kr*r]^2/(4.96*10^11)}, 
    {r, -1.5*λ, +1.5*λ}, 
    PlotRange -> All]

Fθ = 
  Plot[{0.2*kz*kr^2/(2*ω)*1/r*BesselJ[1, kr*r]^2/(4.96*10^11)}, 
    {r, -1.5*λ, +1.5*λ}, 
    PlotRange -> All]

Fz = 
  Plot[{kr^3/(2*ω)*1/r*BesselJ[1, kr*r]*(BesselJ[0, kr*r] - 
          BesselJ[2, kr*r])/2/(4.96*10^11)}, 
    {r, -1.5*λ, +1.5*λ}, 
    PlotRange -> All]
```

I used 4.96*10^11 to normalize the data.

As you can see, `Fr`, `Fθ` and `Fz` are in cylindrical coordinate, but there is only one variable, `r` with `{r, -1.5 λ, +1.5 λ}`.

I've searched all day through this forum and tried `VectorPlot3D`, `ListVectorPlot3D`, but failed.

Please, can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: You can get inspiration from this solution https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214989/3d-vectors-wrap-on-the-sphere/215085#215085

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is, that you have a vector field, given in cylindrical coordinates, that only depends on the radius r (Note r should be >0 in cylindrical coordinates). And you want to plot the vectors in a slice with z==0.

Toward this aim we first define the coordinate functions `r[r], \[Theta][r]` and `z[r`] that give the cylindrical coordinates.

Then we need the three cylinder base vectors in cartesian coordinates for our plot. This is done with the the function `cylbas[x,y]`

Next, as the vectors depend only on `r`, we define a function `vec0[r]` that gives the cartesian components of the searched for vectors in the `y==z==0` plane.

Then we rotate the vectors in the plane `y==z==0` around the z-axis. This gives a table of vector called: vecs

Finally we feed vecs to `Graphics3D`, where we change the vectors to Arrows. Here is the code:

```
\[Lambda] = 633*10^(-9);
\[Omega] = 2*\[Pi]*3*10^8/\[Lambda];
k0 = 2 \[Pi]/\[Lambda];
kr = 1.05*k0;
kz = Sqrt[kr^2 - k0^2];

r[r_] = 0.8*kz*kr^2/(2*\[Omega])*1/r*BesselJ[1, kr*r]^2/(4.96*10^11);
\[Theta][r_] = 
  0.2*kz*kr^2/(2*\[Omega])*1/r*BesselJ[1, kr*r]^2/(4.96*10^11);
z[r_] = kr^3/(2*\[Omega])*1/r*
   BesselJ[1, 
    kr*r]*(BesselJ[0, kr*r] - BesselJ[2, kr*r])/2/(4.96*10^11);

cylbase[x_, 
   y_] = {{Cos[ph], Sin[ph], 0}, 
    Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] {- Sin[ph], Cos[ph], 0 }, {0, 0, 1}} /. 
   ph -> ArcTan[x, y];

vec0[r_] = 
  Arrow[{{r, 0, 
     0}, {r, 0, 
      0} + {r[r \[Lambda]], \[Theta][r \[Lambda]], 
       z[r \[Lambda]]}.cylbase[r, 0 ]}];

vecs = Table[
   Rotate[Table[vec0[r ], {r, Table[i, {i, 0.2, 1, 0.05}]}], 
    ph, {0, 0, 1}], {ph, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/5}];

Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.005], 
  Arrowheads[Medium, Appearance -> "Projected"], vecs, Opacity[0.3], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.005}}, 1]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {-.2, 0.4}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
 Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great job! Almost there, how to make the arrows in the same size? I tried to put Scale inside Arrowheads but nothing changed.

Comment: The length of the arrows indicate the magnitude of the vector. You really want all vector the same length?

Comment: Yes, I just want to show the winding trend of these arrows, so it's better to make them in same length.

Comment: make this change to vec0: vec0[r_] = 
  Arrow[{{r, 0, 0}, {r, 0, 0} + 
     0.2 Normalize@{r[r \[Lambda]], \[Theta][r \[Lambda]], 
         z[r \[Lambda]]}.cylbase[r, 0]}];  and change Graphics3D to: Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.008], Arrowheads[Appearance -> "Projected"], 
  vecs, Opacity[0.3], Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.005}}, 1]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
 Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: DanielHuber, normally the magnitude is represented by something like a color, hence why the color changes in OP’s plot. At least, from my understanding. Likely @EricZ can implement something like a color function to illustrate this.

Answer (score 3):

Whether meet your requirements?

```
Clear["`*"];
λ = 633*10^(-9);
ω = 2*π*3*10^8/λ;
k0 = 2 π/λ;
kr = 1.05*k0;
kz = Sqrt[kr^2 - k0^2];
Fr = 0.8*kz*kr^2/(2*ω)*1/r*BesselJ[1, kr*r]^2/(4.96*10^11);
Fθ = 
  0.2*kz*kr^2/(2*ω)*1/r*BesselJ[1, kr*r]^2/(4.96*10^11);
Fz = kr^3/(2*ω)*1/r*
   BesselJ[1, 
    kr*r]*(BesselJ[0, kr*r] - BesselJ[2, kr*r])/2/(4.96*10^11);
{r, θ, z} = {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], z};
{Fx, Fy, Fz} = {Fr, Fθ, 
      Fz}.D[{r, θ, z}, {{x, y, z}}] /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] // 
   Simplify;
vectors = 
 VectorPlot3D[{Fx, Fy, Fz}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 
   1.5}, VectorColorFunction -> "BrightBands", PlotTheme -> "Classic",
   VectorPoints -> {15, 15, 5}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[z] <= .5 && Sqrt[ x^2 + y^2] <= 1.5], 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
```

**Another code**

```
Clear["`*"];
\[Lambda] = 633*10^(-9);
\[Omega] = 2*\[Pi]*3*10^8/\[Lambda];
k0 = 2 \[Pi]/\[Lambda];
kr = 1.05*k0;
kz = Sqrt[kr^2 - k0^2];
Fr = 0.8*kz*kr^2/(2*\[Omega])*1/r*BesselJ[1, kr*r]^2/(4.96*10^11);
F\[Theta] = 
  0.2*kz*kr^2/(2*\[Omega])*1/r*BesselJ[1, kr*r]^2/(4.96*10^11);
Fz = kr^3/(2*\[Omega])*1/r*
   BesselJ[1, 
    kr*r]*(BesselJ[0, kr*r] - BesselJ[2, kr*r])/2/(4.96*10^11);
{r, \[Theta], z} = {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], z};
{Fx, Fy, Fz} = {Fr, F\[Theta], 
      Fz}.D[{r, \[Theta], z}, {{x, y, z}}] /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] // 
   Simplify;
SliceVectorPlot3D[{Fx, Fy, Fz}, 
 z == 0, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> "BrightBands", PlotTheme -> "Classic", 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me, very nice. Go ahead.

Comment: the picture looks pretty, but is there something missing in the code? I ran it on my computer, and it says: Unknown option RegionBoundaryStyle->None. Then I deleted RegionBoundaryStyle->None, it gives me only one arrow.

Comment: @EricZ  I'm using 12.1.1 . You can test another code which I updated.

Comment: Great, many thanks for the code!

Comment: @cvgmt, I try to run your code both,  and it doesn't work on my pc, the first one says RegionBoundaryStyle is not an option for the 3D plot, the second doesn't look similar to the plot in the solution. Please can you check it, maybe I miss something, thanks

Comment: @irondonio  it need 12.1.1 version