Help in Drawing the Figure
I wish to plot the following figure using Mathematica,
Could you please help me ?


Please take a look at Graphics3D, Arrow and Tube. After that, [edit] the question and include the code that you have tried so far :)

Relevant: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/215085/9469

Also look at CirclePoints

Make n arrows on circle with a given arrowLength and arrowWidth:
circleArrows[numberPoints_, arrowLength_, arrowWidth_] :=
 With[{cp = Append[#, 0] & /@ CirclePoints[numberPoints + 1]},
  {Arrowheads[2 arrowWidth], 
     Arrow[Tube[{#, # + arrowLength {0, 0, 1}}, arrowWidth]]} & /@ cp]

Example:
Graphics3D[circleArrows[5, .5, .03]]

Interactive
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{color, circleArrows[n, l, w]}],
 {{n, 5}, 3, 12, 1},
 {{l, .5}, 0.01, 5},
 {{w, .03}, .001, .1},
 {color, Red}
 ]


